# ChainBridge: cb-sol-cli cannot deploy Eth contracts... Cannot find module 'commander'

Tags: chainbridge

Install cb-sol-cli
https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-deploy/blob/master/cb-sol-cli/README.md

`$ make install`

Then try to run the ChainBridge following this guide
https://chainbridge.chainsafe.io/local/

```
On-Chain Setup 
Deploy Contracts

To deploy the contracts on to the Ethereum chain, run the following:
Deploy Contracts:
$ cb-sol-cli deploy --all --relayerThreshold 1
```

Then I got:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
Require stack:
- /mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/mnt/sda3/polkadot/chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli/index.js' ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into `chainbridge-deploy/cb-sol-cli`

then run `npm install`

then `cb-sol-cli deploy --all --relayerThreshold 1`